# Android: Getting a NoClassDefFoundError in my own class

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, osx-mavericks

I am developing an Android project that was working fine. After updating to **OSX Mavericks**, when I opened Android Studio, it showed a message saying that it needed to update JDK. I did so and everything went fine. I can compile the app, but it throws a `NoClassDefFoundError` in one of my own classes.

```
10-25 10:24:10.403  12318-12318/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.vitasalutis.client.main.parameterwidgets.graphs.ParameterWidgetGraphicalView
        at com.vitasalutis.client.main.parameterwidgets.MainWidget.<init>(MainWidget.java:215)
        at com.vitasalutis.client.main.ParameterMenuFragment.onCreateView(ParameterMenuFragment.java:107)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:861)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1137)
```

The `ParameterWidgetGraphicalView` belongs to the **same** module and project as the activity, so it's not a linking problem.

I am compiling and testing with API-17.

[What I have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/):

- Downloaded JDK7, and used that on the project.
- Reinstalled Android Studio completely from scratch ([deleted all user files](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181)).
- Created project from scratch and copy-pasted the previous source.
- Compiled and tested another similar project (not gradle, though) in Android Studio. It worked fine.
- Went back to my Win8 machine. The app works fine...

Other questions on the net suggest that it may be a SDK/JDK version problem. That doesn't explain why I am able to compile/run other projects.

Thanks! 
I miss my Mac...

**[UPDATE] Solved!**
The problem was not that it couldn't find the ParameterWidgetGraphicalView class, but its parent that was compiled in a jar.
I re-compiled that jar, and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

The problem was not that it couldn't find the ParameterWidgetGraphicalView class, but its parent.

The parent was compiled in a jar. I don't know why it didn't work, but I re-compiled that jar, and now it works.

Probably something to do with JDK versions...